# Spinner in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I define a spinner, when the page need to do some thing for example bring some data from database i want to show it, and when its done i want to hide this spinner, so i decide to define some thing like this in `Layout.cshtml` :

```
<div id="SpinnerDiv" ng-show="showSpinner">
   <div id="AllContent">
      <!--I put all of my contents here-->
   <div>
</div>
```

but there is a problem in this method, when i put `ng-show` to `False` it will hide it's child too, so its not the right way, anyone one can help how can i implement a spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

Your spinner should be managed by adding/removing a specific css class to `<div id="AllContent">`